# Selenium clicks on Browser's url rather than search box of website

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to automate search box of Amazon.in and when i try to enter some string over there, it rather points towards the address bar of browser. My code for the same.

Note- I have already tried with different xpaths using firebug and also through tag traversing.

Also please let me know why we have to use always build and perform methods with actions?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://amazon.in");
    Actions action=new Actions(driver);
    WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='nav-link-yourAccount']/span[2]"));
    action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
    WebElement search= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']"));
    action.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).moveToElement(search).sendKeys("teststring").build().perform();
    action.contextClick(search).build().perform();
}
```

Comment: Anyone to bail out on this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://amazon.in");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']"));

        //Search using actions by combining entering search string and then hit enter
        action.click(search).sendKeys("Test").sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();

        // This also works where it does the same without actions class
        search.sendKeys("test");
        search.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    }
```

In your code:

Below line enters teststring into the browser search instead of the amazon search bar because you are just moving to that element and not clicking on it.   `action.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).moveToElement(search).sendKeys("teststring").build().perform();`

This like right clicks / context click on the search bar
`action.contextClick(search).build().perform();`

---

From the API doc:

> build() Generates a composite action containing all actions so far,
>   ready to be performed (and resets the internal builder state, so
>   subsequent calls to build() will contain fresh sequences).
>
> perform() A convenience method for performing the actions without
>   calling build() first

Please read below links for a clear picture on them:
[LinkOne](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html)
[LinkTwo](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions)